# How to completely remove or disable Version Control integration in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

After finding out my build issues had to do with version-control mechanisms locking files and preventing them from being cleaned I determined that I don't want this integration.

How do I completely remove version-control mechanisms from Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to take this path:

In options, set version control to None:

[image]

And uninstall any extensions that act on Version Control.

Alternatively, file a bug on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: Just disabling the Plug-in Selection for Source Control seems to have disabled it :) Tyvm! :)

Comment: Until you start VS again... it is really a pain. There seems to be still no solution araound.